# MySql Java separating identical errors thrown

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am dealing with insert statements into a database on `Mysql`. I have a users table where I have a unique key on the username and on the email. This way I can get an `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` when I try inserting a new user into the database. The problem is if both the username and email throw the same exception if there are duplicate entries, how can I tell which one is throwing the exception. 
The end goal I want to tell the user whether that username is already taken.. or if that username is already registered.
Thanks,

Comment: ** or if the email is already registered

Comment: Do you throw the exception once if either fails? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @achAmháin As of right now, if I catch that SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException which would only happen if there a unique key violation..I only throw one SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException error.. I am not aware of how to separate two of the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the exception message contains the object name of the violated constraint. Whenever an SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException is thrown, you can check which constraint name is within the exception message and set display message based on that.